# Select a Square Matrix from Excel table (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

How can I select a square Matrix according to a factor number?

For example, if cells(1,1)=4, I should select 4*4 matrix, starts from a certain cell, then create a loop to continue the selections for the next 4*4 matrix both horizontally and vertically.

Many thanks!

I tried to use "Step i" based on the factor number, to avoid overlapping issue. So if i=4, basically it would go every 4 steps away horizontally, I just wonder if I could use "step j" as well, so how to create a loop to select a range by range?

Comment: What code have you tried? Do you have an idea on how you think the logic should go? It's hard to know exactly what you want. For example... Do the matrices overlap? Does it matter whether you go horizontally or vertically first? When do we stop finding new matrices? What do you mean by "select ... matrix"?

Comment: This is quite unclear. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

As per your example, the following code snippet selects the Worksheet `Range` pertinent to the content of the `Cell(1,1)`:

```
Sub SelectRange()
    Dim size As Integer
    size = Cells(1, 1).Value
    Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(1 + size, 2 + size)).Select
End Sub
```

Hope this may help.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Sub DynamicSelectMatrix()

        size = 4
             For s = 1 To 10 
                 For t = 1 To 10 
                     Range(Cells(6 + size * (s - 1), 5 + size * (t - 1)), Cells(6 + size * s - 1, 5 + size * t - 1)).Select
                 Next t
             Next s

 End Sub
```